# OpenCV find inner сontours

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I want to get an outline with text.My entire frame is being cut out.How do I cut a rectangle with text?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzkL9.jpg)

```
def img_counter_max(image_file: str):
img = cv2.imread(image_file)
# grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # меняем цветовую модель с BGR на HSV
cv2.waitKey(0)
# binarize
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.waitKey(0)
# find contours
ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
# sort contours
sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])
# sorted_ctrs sorted(ctrs, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[0]
contour_sizes = [(cv2.contourArea(contour), contour) for contour in sorted_ctrs]
biggest_contour = max(contour_sizes, key=lambda x: x[0])[1]
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(biggest_contour)
roi = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
cv2.imwrite("C:\\Users\\dennn\\PycharmProjects\\untitled2\\imag\\roi1.jpg", roi)
cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (90, 255, 0), 2)
from tensorflow.python import Size
resize_img = cv2.resize(img, (512,512))
# cv2.resize(img, Size(512,512), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2.namedWindow("Display frame", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cv2.imshow('Display frame', resize_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Now it turns out like this. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmEEr.jpg)
After finding the rectangle with the text, I want to find the characters.

I tried to find separate characters, but it didn't work

```
enter def letters_extract(image_file: str, out_size=28):
img = cv2.imread(image_file)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
img_erode = cv2.erode(thresh, np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8), iterations=1)
# Get contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_erode, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
output = img.copy()
letters = []
for idx, contour in enumerate(contours):
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    if hierarchy[0][idx][3] == 0:
        cv2.rectangle(output, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (90, 0, 255), 2)#(70, 0, 0), 1
        letter_crop = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        # Resize letter canvas to square
        size_max = max(w, h)
        letter_square = 255 * np.ones(shape=[size_max, size_max], dtype=np.uint8)
        if w > h:
            # Enlarge image top-bottom
            y_pos = size_max // 2 - h // 2
            letter_square[y_pos:y_pos + h, 0:w] = letter_crop
        elif w < h:
            # Enlarge image left-right
            x_pos = size_max // 2 - w // 2
            letter_square[0:h, x_pos:x_pos + w] = letter_crop
        else:
            letter_square = letter_crop

        # Resize letter to 28x28 and add letter and its X-coordinate
        letters.append((x, w, cv2.resize(letter_square, (out_size, out_size), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)))

# Sort array in place by X-coordinate
letters.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=False)
#Save letters
# counter = 1
for i in range(len(letters)):
    for j in range(len(letters[i])):
        cv2.imshow('0',letters[i][j])
        cv2.waitKey(0)
#     cv2.imwrite("imag/"+str(counter)+".jpg", letters[i][j])
#     counter = counter + 1

return letterscode here
```

То что я хочу получить [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd6ie.jpg)

Comment: The output you are looking for is unclear. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Rick M. I want to get this image, or just where the text is. [link](https://ibb.co/F48YBgZ) or [link](https://ibb.co/t8hNkM2)

Comment: In that case, don't get the biggest contour because that is entire frame, try to iterate over the sorted contours to find the approximate contourArea/boundingRect that satisfies your requirements

Comment: I didn't understand how to use contour Area to limit the size of a single character. I do everything for the sake of finding the contours of symbols that will be further recognized by the neural network.

Comment: Added the code where I tried to apply boundingRect

Comment: I tried playing around with the contourArea parameter and it doesn't seem to work well if you just want to extract each character as a single contour. For a range of contourArea between 100 and 250, it finds most of them but not all

Comment: How do I set two borders in the contour Area? I'll try to find a large frame this way.

Comment: Why do you need to set the two border? The contourArea is needed only to filter the contours